# Google+/Flickr Justified Image Layout in Using Python / Flask-Classy

Tags: python, image, layout, google-plus, flickr

I would like to make a website where I can share my favorite pictures using a similar layout that you see Google and Flickr use.
you can see the beautiful layout here:

[image]

I found this (http://jsbin.com/upinek/15) which looks really good but I want to use my own pictures. So I'm thinking that maybe I could add all my pictures to a folder (and add these pictures in many different sizes which would be reloaded based on device/width) and then use python to get all the images from the folder containing all the images, and use some lazyload to make sure that user wouldn't need to wait for all the images to be loaded before they would be placed in the beautiful layout.

In addition, I think it would be great if the images were loaded in random order (maybe using some shuffle algorithm?) whenever the user visited the site so that returning visitors would always look at new pictures, etc..

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site! Your post is a bit of a "wall of text", maybe you wouldn't mind trying to edit it into better shape?

Comment: Hi :), I will try to make it easier to understand, thanks